# music from PHPMyAdmin to play in a modal box

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to  to put a music from my table in phpmyadmin into a modal box. I have been able to have them in a modal box but it puts all of them in and I only want the specific music allocated to a specific button to play.

Here is my code:

audio.php

```
<?php

/*the variables*/
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "arashi_site";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
/*sql to extract the data*/
$sql = "SELECT * FROM music";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
/*condition to see if there are any results*/
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
/*a loop function to output */
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
/*echos the data within each column*/
         /*within the final <td>, audio controls will be echoed to play the song files. When the user clicks any of the buttons in the audio controls, they will remain in the second section the the site and not be sent back to the top.*/
   echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-lg' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>" . $row["song_name"] . "</button>";
   }
   }


 else {
    echo "0 results";
 }

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

audio2.php:

```
<?php
/*the variables*/
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "arashi_site";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
/*sql to extract the data*/
$sql = "SELECT song_name FROM music";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
/*condition to see if there are any results*/
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
/*a loop function to output */
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

 echo "<audio id='sound' controls>
        <source src='audio/" .$row['song_name']."' type='audio/mpeg'>
                    Your browser does not support the audio element.
   </audio>";
}
}

else {
    echo "0 results";
 }

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: phpmyadmin is not a database, just another script

Comment: Its where my music is stored

Comment: no its not. the mysql database  is where it is stored

Comment: How will I obtain music from the sql database?

Comment: Do you need jquery to play music?

Comment: I may do? I'm slightly new to this but i know how to play the music i just want a specific sound to play when the button for it is clicked